# Package names in project generated from Maven archetype

Tags: java, maven

How are the package names determined while creating a project from a Maven archetype?

I figured out that it's composed by the groupId given while creating the project + the path in the archetype after src/main/java. (Correct me if I'm wrong)

Example:

Archetype folder tree src/main/java/service with groupId *it.foo.stub* creates the package *it.foo.stub.service*

For just a package I'd like to change the first part of the package name to something like *it.bar.mock.business*, but until now I haven't been able to find out how to. Is it even possible?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can create any package that you want. The package is mostly defined by the directory anyway. In your `archetype-metadata.xml` file you can configure your archetype to generate any directories you want. This shows how to create two different packages in generated projects:

```
<fileSets>
    <!-- Create a package using the groupId -->
    <fileSet filtered="true" encoding="UTF-8">
        <directory>src/main/java/__packageInPathFormat__</directory>
    </fileSet>
    <!-- Create a fixed package: it.bar.mock.business -->
    <fileSet filtered="true" encoding="UTF-8">
        <directory>src/main/java/it/bar/mock/business</directory>
    </fileSet>
</fileSets>
```

This assumes you are using Maven Archetype 2.x.

Comment: Thanks for including both examples, I ended up creating another package dinamically.