# Change package property in Maven Archetype

Tags: maven, maven-3, maven-archetype

I created a Maven Archetype. My `META-INF/maven/archetype-metadata.xml` looks like this:

```
<archetype-descriptor xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-archetype-plugin/archetype-descriptor/1.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-archetype-plugin/archetype-descriptor/1.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/archetype-descriptor-1.0.0.xsd">

  <fileSets>
    <fileSet filtered="true" packaged="true" encoding="UTF-8" >
      <directory>src/main/java</directory>
    </fileSet>
  </fileSets>

</archetype-descriptor>
```

This works, as in that it creates a Java source folder and puts my classes in the package as defined by the `groupId` and the `artifactId`.

However, I want to modify his package name. For example, if my groupId is `com.example` and my artifactId `wvdz`, then my package should be:

```
com.example.wvdz.mypackage
```

**Question**: How do I accomplish this?

Comment: What about [Maven - Guide to creating archetypes](https://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-creating-archetypes.html) using the mvn archetype:generate?

Comment: Also take a look to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20403157/package-names-in-project-generated-from-maven-archetype

Answer (score 35, accepted):

To accomplish your objectives and since you are already using the `packaged` attribute to `true` (explained later), you can simply add directories to your path below.

Keeping the same configuration, with an additional `include` element as following:

```
<fileSets>
    <fileSet filtered="true" packaged="true" encoding="UTF-8" >
      <directory>src/main/java</directory>
        <includes>
            <include>**/*.java</include>
        </includes>       
    </fileSet>
</fileSets>
```

You could then place under `src/main/java/mypackage` your Java sources *templated* where the package statement would be as following:

```
package ${package}.mypackage
```

Note the `.mypackage` reflects exactly the `mypackage` folder directly under `src/main/java`. However, when creating the archetype, Maven will then place as a folder (and as such as a package) in between the ${package} property value, which by default would be the ${groupId}.

You can always pass the `-Dpackage` property and override it the default value (the `groupId`), which will then be used as a prefix of the package, based on the template above.

This happens because of the `packaged` attribute set to `true` in the `fileSet` section above. In this case `true` means: add to it the folder hierarchy specified by the `${package}` property. Setting it at `false` would result in `${package}` ignored, which can be used if you really want to hard-code the folder structure and obviously reflect it in to the `package` statement of your Java code, for consistency.

---

The behavior above is documented in the official [How is metadata about an archetype stored?](http://maven.apache.org/archetype/maven-archetype-plugin/specification/archetype-metadata.html):

> the archetype defines a single fileset:
>
> - the fileset will take all the files in `archetype-resources/src/main/java` that match the `**/*.java` pattern
> - the selected files will be generated using the Velocity engine (`filtered=true`)
> - the files will be generated in the `src/main/java` directory of the generated project in the same directory as in the JAR file, but with that directory prepended by the `package` property.

And also:

> Filesets can be `packaged`, which means the selected files will be generated/copied in a directory structure that is prepended by the package property. They can be non-packaged, which means that the selected files will be generated/copied without that prepend.

The same details (about the `packaged` property) can also be found in the official [Archetype Descriptor Model](http://maven.apache.org/archetype/archetype-models/archetype-descriptor/archetype-descriptor.html).

---

Another possible solution is to use an additional property or define your `package` property value directly in the `archetype-metadata.xml` file as following:

```
<archetype-descriptor
    xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-archetype-plugin/archetype-descriptor/1.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-archetype-plugin/archetype-descriptor/1.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/archetype-descriptor-1.0.0.xsd">

    <fileSets>
        <fileSet filtered="true" packaged="true" encoding="UTF-8">
            <directory>src/main/java</directory>
        </fileSet>
    </fileSets>

    <requiredProperties>
        <requiredProperty key="package">
            <defaultValue>${groupId}.${artifactId}.mypackage</defaultValue>
        </requiredProperty>
    </requiredProperties>

</archetype-descriptor>
```

Note the new `requiredProperties` section: here we are setting the default value for the `package` property, no need to provide it at runtime anymore (yet possible to override the value above though).

As such, the Java source template under `src/main/java` (no need for further static folders) would simply be:

```
package ${package}
```

During the creation (`archetype:generate`) Maven will then use the `com.sample.something.mypackage` as package value (in the Java source file) and populate the `packageInPathFormat` property with the value `com/sample/something/mypackage` (the same property, but in path format) and create the desired package hierarchy, consistent with what the Java source code would expect to be placed in.

Comment: None of those methods seem to work for me. Adding the correct package name in the Java class works, but the class is not put in the appropriate folder when I create a new project - it's still being put in the groupId.artifactId folder

Comment: @wvdz did you apply the same exact approach and re-installed (`mvn clean install`) the archetype in your machine before running a new `mvn archetype:generate ...`) for a new project? Both approaches work for me. Did you create new folders in `src/main/java` as described?

Comment: I'm using the eclipse interface. To be able to select the archetype when creating a new Project I use Run As Maven Build... with parameter `clean install archetype:update-local-catalog`. This should be the same as doing `mvn clean install archetype:update-local-catalog` on the prompt. After that I just select it when creating a new project. I added a required property 'package' and have the default value be ${package}.mypackage.

Comment: I just tried it with the command line and that actually works, with providing `${groupId}.${artifactId}.mypackage` as the default value for the package property. The problem in Eclipse seems to be that it will always supply the -dPackage property, overriding the defined property.

Comment: the major important thing i took from this was `-Dpackage` if not specified will use `-DgroupId`. By specifying `-Dpackage` i got what i needed

Comment: what if my artifactId have "-" like `clean-data`, as java Convention, the package name should be `clean.data` ；but I think this is too many folders for the project.