# Maven archetype package construction

Tags: maven, maven-archetype

I created my own archetype which has a custom `pom.xml` and a custom `class` in a package like this: `${groupId}.${artifactId}.core`

The problem is at package. When I create a maven project with my archetype the package it is not like `${groupId}.${artifactId}.core`. It is only `${groupId}`.

This is the generated class by archetype:

[image]

But the tree is like this (package is not builded how I want):

[image]

Why my project is not builded how I expect and how I done this?

Here is the tree of project from where I generate archetype

[image]

MainCore.java

```
package ${package}.core;

import fl.raul.libs.methods.Common;

public class MainCore{

    public static void main(String[] args){

        //REMINDER : update version of fl.raul.libs - if needed.
        Common.testLibrary();

    }

}
```

archetype.xml

```
<archetype xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-archetype-plugin/archetype/1.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
           xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-archetype-plugin/archetype/1.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/archetype-1.0.0.xsd">

    <id>libs-archetype</id>

    <sources>
        <source>src/main/java/core/MainCore.java</source>
    </sources>

    <allowPartial>true</allowPartial>

</archetype>
```

P.S.: I think it is something from Intellij. I tested this archetype in Eclipse and package is how it should be (`fl.raul.testers.core`).

Comment: please prefer text to image wherever possible (maincore.java, archetype.xml)

Comment: @xerx593 thanks for advice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please **move the file into correct folder** (`core`) **and adjust** `archetype.xml`, I think that is what breaks the default behavior, here.

Alternatively to `package ${groupId}.${artifactId}.core` you can use `package ${package}.core;`.

`${package}` property can be provided on archetype generation and defaults (if omit) to `${groupId}.${artifactId}`.

Please also refer to this "nice answer" & "wider scope question":

https://stackoverflow.com/a/39251046/592355

Comment: Now the package is `fl.raul.core`. Still missing `artifactId`. But I think is something from Intellij, because if I use this archetype in Eclipse, there is presence `artifactId` -  `fl.raul.testers.core`

Comment: then plz also try with `testers/core` (folder) ... (`archetypeId == 'testers' ?)

Comment: `archetypeId == 'testers' ? - yes, I edited my first comment.

Comment: and please have a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39251046/592355)

Comment: That's it. So, I changed my `archetype.xml` to `archetype-metadata.xml` and there I used `<requiredProperties>` and I declared the key `package` with value `${groupId}.${artifactId}` (I think you can use any key if you don't want to change the default value of `package`) and now It works. Really thanks!